# Can you set dynamic column names in SQL SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to do something like SELECT SomeColumnName AS @ANewColumnNameStoredInAVariable FROM SomeTable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happened to displaying data in your app/report accordingly? You have the name (you're passing it as parameter), you might as well use it in the app/report.

Comment: Its not that simple. Our app has a dynamic number of names. And on top of that, all this occurs in a WHILE loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `EXEC` Statement. As in:

```
EXEC('SELECT SomeColumnName AS ' + @ANewColumnNameStoredInAVariable + ' FROM SomeTable')
```

Comment: Is there any other alternative? I don't want to put everything in an EXEC clause...because this is part of a much larger script...that uses temporary tables and other things.

Comment: Nope, there is no other alternative at least for dynamic column names.